# IBM Mobile First Push Notification Security Test

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

**What I want to achieve:**

Change mobileSecurityTest to customSecurityTest to achieve push notification.

**I've tried:**

According to [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_security_tests.html), in authenticationConfig.xml

If we use this mobileSecurityTest code:

```
    <mobileSecurityTest name="PushSecurityTest">
        <testUser realm="PushAppRealm"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
```

The equivalent would be:

```
    <customSecurityTest name="PushSecurityTest">
      <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" />
      <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" />
      <test realm="PushAppRealm" isInternalUserID="true" />
      <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalUserID="true" />
    </customSecurityTest>
```

**Problem:**

However, after I changed it from mobileSecurityTest code to custom security test, I'm hitting this error:

> [ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project
>   /EventSourceNotifications [project EventSourceNotifications] Error
>   creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService'
>   while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in
>   URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while
>   setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0251E: conf/authenticationConfig.xml:
>   PushSecurityTest has duplicated entry with isInternalUserID=true
>   [project EventSourceNotifications]
>
> [ERROR   ] Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService'
>   while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in
>   URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while
>   setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0251E: conf/authenticationConfig.xml:
>   PushSecurityTest has duplicated entry with isInternalUserID=true
>   [project EventSourceNotifications] Error creating bean with name
>   'taskManager' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService'
>   while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in
>   URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while
>   setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0251E: conf/authenticationConfig.xml:
>   PushSecurityTest has duplicated entry with isInternalUserID=true
>   [project EventSourceNotifications]
>
> [ERROR   ] EventSourceNotifications: worklight///10.128.1.179:
>   2016-06-16T03:40:52.129Z: Error creating bean with name 'taskManager'
>   defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService'
>   while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in
>   URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while
>   setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL
>   [wsjar:file:/Users/keatooon/eclipseWorkspaceJustinPush1/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0251E: conf/authenticationConfig.xml:
>   PushSecurityTest has duplicated entry with isInternalUserID=true
>   [project EventSourceNotifications]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log shows:

> PushSecurityTest has duplicated entry with isInternalUserID=true [project EventSourceNotifications]

Remove `isInternalUserID` from `PushAppRealm`.